# Substitute string in file with file content while keeping tabs

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I would like to ask how to substitute string in file with a file content while keeping tabs. So e.g.:

File to transform:

```
first line
second line
        string_to_substitute
forth line
fifth line
```

File with content:

```
{
    "string1":"test",
    "string2":"test2"
}
```

The result that I would like to achieve (substituing `string_to_substitute` with file content):

```
first line
second line
        {
            "string1":"test",
            "string2":"test2"
        }
forth line
fifth line
```

I tried `sed` and `perl` substitutions but only achieved something like:

```
first line
second line
        {
    "string1":"test",
    "string2":"test2"
}
forth line
fifth line
```

or

```
first line
second line
{
    "string1":"test",
    "string2":"test2"
}
forth line
fifth line
```

Comment: Do you want to manipulate a json document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This single awk command can handle this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
   a = a (a=="" ? "":RS) $0
   next
}
/string_to_substitute/ {
   sub(/[^[:blank:]].*$/, "")
   gsub(/\n/, "\n" $0, a)
   $0 = $0 a
} 1' content.txt file.txt

first line
second line
    {
        "string1":"test",
        "string2":"test2"
    }
forth line
fifth line
```

Comment: I have a small question. How can I pass a variable into the "/string_to_substitute" pattern? something like `awk -v pattern=$mypattern '/pattern/ {...}'` ? I can't get it working

Comment: You can use: **`awk -v kw='string_to_substitute' 'FNR==NR{a = a (a=="" ? "":RS) $0; next} $0 ~ kw{sub(/[^[:blank:]].*$/, ""); gsub(/\n/, "\n" $0, a); $0 = $0 a} 1' content.txt file.txt`**

Comment: I tried exactly that but I can't get it working. Well I call the awk command in loop and my patterns look like `inject(x-y.json)`, I also tried escaping the parentheses, no success. I have this: `for inject in "${unique_inject[@]}"
do
    p="inject\($inject\)"
    awk -v pattern="$p" 'FNR==NR{
    a = a (a=="" ? "":RS) $0
    next
    }
    $0 ~ pattern {
    sub(/[^[:blank:]].*$/, "")
    gsub(/\n/, "\n" $0, a)
    $0 = $0 a
    } 1' $inject file.txt
done` where `unique_inject` array contains  something like `x-x.json`, `x-y.json`, etc

Comment: Ok don't escape search string and use `awk -v pattern="$p" 'FNR==NR{a = a (a=="" ? "":RS) $0; next} index($0, pattern) {sub(/[^[:blank:]].*$/, ""); gsub(/\n/, "\n" $0, a); $0 = $0 a} 1' content.txt file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk solution:

```
$ awk -v f=content '/string_to_substitute/{sub(/[^\t].*/, ""); while (getline new<f) print $0 new; close(f); next} 1' file1
first line
second line
        {
                "string1":"test",
                "string2":"test2"
        }
forth line
fifth line
```

Because this approach does not require reading either file into memory, this should work even with large files.

#### How it works

- `-v f=content`

  This assigns the name of the file with the new content to an awk variable `f`.
- `/string_to_substitute/{...}`

  When we reach a line that matches the regex `string_to_substitute`, we execute the commands in the curly braces.  We discuss each of these commands below:

  - `sub(/[^\t].*/, "")`

    This removes from the current line, `$0`, everything from the non-tab character to the end of the line.  In other words, this keeps only the indentation tabs from the current line.
  - `while (getline new<f) print $0 new`

    This loops over the file `f` and prints each line with the desired indentation.
  - `close(f)`

    This closes the file `f`.
  - `next`

    This tells awk to skip the remaining commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `1`

  We we get here, we are not on the `string_to_substitute` line.

  `1` is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

#### Multi-line version of the command

For those who find it easier to understand a command if it is spread over multiple lines:

```
awk -v f=content '

    /string_to_substitute/{
        sub(/[^\t].*/, "")
        while (getline new<f)
           print $0 new
        close(f)
        next
    }

    1

    ' file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($content_filename, $to_transform_filename) = @ARGV;

my @content_lines = do {
    open my $CONTENT, '<', $content_filename or die $!;
    <$CONTENT>;
};

open my $TO_TRANSFORM, '<', $to_transform_filename or die $!;
while (<$TO_TRANSFORM>) {
    if (my ($prefix) = /^(\s*)string_to_substitute$/) {
        print "$prefix$_" for @content_lines;
    } else {
        print;
    }
}
```

Save as `transform`, run as `perl transform -- content-file file-to-transfer`.

It first reads the lines of the "content" file into the @content_lines array.
Then, it reads the other file line by line, and when the line contains the string to replace, it remembers the whitespace `\s*` before it and prepends it to each line in the array. Non-matching lines are printed without any change.

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash solution - give content file as the argument

```
contentf=$1
pat="^(\s*)string_to_substitute"
while IFS= read -r line; do
  unset IFS
  if [[ ! $line =~ $pat ]]; then
    echo "$line"
    continue
  fi
  pfx=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
# can use sed instead of inner while read loop
# sed "s/^/$pfx/" $contentf
  while IFS= read -r contentline; do
    unset IFS
    echo "$pfx$contentline"
  done <$contentf
done
```